# C# Deserialize JSON into mulitple/different lists

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have 3 different lists in "UrnikPrevozov" class, I want to populate them with data from JSON for each list, but I am not quite sure how to correctly do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my json:

```
{
  "UrnikAvtobus": [
    {
      "Linija": 34,
      "Trajanje": "01:15:00",
      "Voznik": "Rojko Mulic",
      "Vstop": "Velenje",
      "Izstop": "Maribor",
      "CenaVozovnice": 2.90
    }
  ],
  
  "UrnikAvto": [
    {
      "Znamka": "MERCEDES",
      "Registerska": "LJ 455-AA",
      "Vinjeta": 0,
      "Vstop": "Maribor",
      "Izstop": "Velenje",
      "CenaVozovnice": 5.40
    }
  ],

  "UrnikKombi": [
    {
      "Sedezi": 8,
      "Odhod": "2022-12-12T09:15:00",
      "Prihod": "2022-12-12T12:31:00",
      "Vstop": "Maribor",
      "Izstop": "Ljubljana",
      "CenaVozovnice": 3.70
    }
  ]
}
```

My UrnikPrevozov class where I want to bind the data to the lists:

```
public class UrnikPrevozov : Prevoz
{
    public List<AvtobusniPrevoz> UrnikBus { get; set; }

    public List<AvtoPrevoz> UrnikAvto { get; set; }

    public List<KombiPrevoz> UrnikKombi { get; set; }

}
```

This is how I read my json:

```
public void LoadJson()
{
    string data = File.ReadAllText("./Data/data.json");

    var urniki = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UrnikPrevozov>(data);
}
```

AvtoPrevoz class

```
  public class AvtoPrevoz : Prevoz
  {

    public string Znamka { get; set; }
    public string Registerska { get; set; }
    public Vinjeta Vinjeta { get; set; }


    public AvtoPrevoz(string znamka, string registerska, Vinjeta vinjeta, string vstop, string izstop, double cenaVozovnice) : base(vstop, izstop, cenaVozovnice)
    {
      Znamka = znamka;
      Registerska = registerska;
      Vinjeta = vinjeta;
    }
}
```

Prevoz class

```
public abstract class Prevoz
{
    public string Vstop { get; set; }
    public string Izstop { get; set; }
    public double CenaVozovnice { get; set; }

    protected Prevoz(string vstop, string izstop, double cenaVozovnice)
    {
        Vstop = vstop;
        Izstop = izstop;
        CenaVozovnice = cenaVozovnice;
    }
}
```

Method call in main:

```
UrnikPrevozov urnik = new UrnikPrevozov();
urnik.LoadJson();
```

Comment: So you defined your other classes?

Comment: Yes, all of classes are defined.

Comment: You got an error then because your code looks pretty good.

Comment: Code runs but the lists don't get populated with the data from JSON.

Comment: The code you shared so far looks good. What do the other classes look like? Especially `Prevoz`, since `UrnikPrevozov` inherits it and it already looks to have everything you need to deserialize the sample JSON, but also `AvtobusniPrevoz`, `AvtoPrevoz` and `KombiPrevoz`?

Comment: If I use jsonutils.com and convert your JSON to classes, it all works for me.  We need to see your other classes.

Comment: I have added Prevoz and AvtoPrevoz for the reference. Could the problem be inheritance?

Comment: The parameters to your constructors, remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UrnikPrevozov` class should not be inheriting `Prevoz` since it does not need the fields `Prevoz` has. And you would need parameterless constructors for all your classes.

Update: Full working code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    string json = File.ReadAllText("./Data/data.json");
    
    UrnikPrevozov urnik = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UrnikPrevozov>(json);

    Console.WriteLine(urnik.UrnikAvto.First().Vstop);
  }
}

public class AvtobusniPrevoz : Prevoz
{
  public int Linija { get; set; }
  public string Trajanje { get; set; }
  public string Voznik { get; set; }
}

public class AvtoPrevoz : Prevoz
{
  public string Znamka { get; set; }
  public string Registerska { get; set; }
  public int Vinjeta { get; set; }
}

public class KombiPrevoz : Prevoz
{
  public int Sedezi { get; set; }
  public DateTime Odhod { get; set; }
  public DateTime Prihod { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Prevoz
{
  public string Vstop { get; set; }
  public string Izstop { get; set; }
  public double CenaVozovnice { get; set; }
}

public class UrnikPrevozov
{
  public List<AvtobusniPrevoz> UrnikBus { get; set; }

  public List<AvtoPrevoz> UrnikAvto { get; set; }

  public List<KombiPrevoz> UrnikKombi { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark the answer as correct if this is what fixed it so it can help others having similar issues.

Comment: Hasn't fixed the problem, I meant that I removed the inheriting in UrnikPrevozov.

Comment: I have updated the answer with some working code.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in UrnikPrevozov class , replace UrnikBus by UrnikAvtobus, also you don't need any base class here. After this everything will be working properly (tested in Visual Studio)

```
public class UrnikPrevozov
{
    public List<AvtobusniPrevoz> UrnikAvtobus { get; set; }

    public List<AvtoPrevoz> UrnikAvto { get; set; }

    public List<KombiPrevoz> UrnikKombi { get; set; }
}
```